# Why VSTS uses non-standard git commit messages?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit, pull-request

There are lot of guides about how a git commit message should be formatted ([like this](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/)). Near all of them states that the message should be in imperative mood and not in past tense. There is a very good argumanet about that:

> "Git itself uses the imperative whenever it creates a commit on your
>   behalf. For example, the default message created when using `git merge`
>   reads: *Merge branch 'myfeature'* "

Then the default commit message for a pull request in VSTS reads:

> "Merge**d** PR: XYZ"

Why?...

Comment: You can suggest MS to change it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk. There is already one https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20328487-change-default-title-for-pull-request-commits-to-n

Comment: I didn't see it, now it got my vote :)

Answer (score 0):

No matter which mood/rule is used for git commit message, the purpose of git commit message is make it clearly to describe what happened for each commit.

For the commit message for a directly merge (such as use `git merge` command directly), the commit message usually `as Merge branch 'branchname'` or `Merge branch 'master' into branchname` etc.

While the commit message for a merged commit by pull request, the default commit message is defined by the git server (such as VSTS, github etc) where your git repo hosted.

And it's a good hahbit to **add the pull request information in commit message** since the commit is merged by PR.

As you found, the default merge commit message in VSTS pull request like `Merged PR <pull request ID>: branch1 to branch2`.

Additional, such as GitHub, the default merge for pull request like `Merge pull request #<pull request ID> from account/branch`.

If you want to **use your own commit message for merging VSTS pull request**, just **custom the commit message as you need in the text box** before clicking Complete merge button (such as change the default message `Merged PR 118: master to b1` in text box in below example).

[image]

Comment: It's clear, we tried this, but somebody always forgets to do that so currently we have mixed Merge PR... and Merged PR... comments. I just don't understand why MS goes against everyone else with comment conventions.

Comment: @csadam If you think it necessary to change/custom the default merge commit message for VSTS PR, feel free to create an user voice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) for what you think :)  And if the answer explain the reason for "Why VSTS uses non-standard git commit messages" clearly, could you mark the answer? And it will also benefit other members who have similar confusions.

Comment: I agree with @csadam, We have the same issue. I found several posts on different forums where people are trying to do the same found even a request  to Microsoft from a couple of years ago, but no change yet.

Comment: This is even more desirable with squashed commits. We just want a clean history of the actual changes without the "Merged" prefix.